# Javascript search filter to remove page elements

Tags: javascript

My brain is stuck and I cant get the code below to work.

What I have is a search bar at the top of a website full of links and I'd like to filter out the links as the user types in the bar.

Here is a snippet of the webpage:

```
<input type="text" id="resourceSearch" onkeyup="resourceFilter" placeholder="Filter resources by name..">

<div id="resourceTiles" class="resource-tiles">

    <a class="resource-tile-container" target="_blank" href="http://hostname/cacti/">
        <div class="resource-tile-icon-container">
            <img src="/media/tile-icons/analytics.png">
        </div>
        <div class="resource-tile-title-container">
            <p>Cacti Traffic Graphing</p>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
```

And the Javascript I'm trying to use:

```
function resourceFilter() {
    var input, filter, tiles, tile, resource, i;
    input = document.getElementById("resourceSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    tiles = document.getElementById("resourceTiles");
    tile = tiles.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
        resource = tile[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        if (resource) {
            if (resource.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tile[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tile[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

I'm new to Javascript and tried to re-purpose some code I found elsewhere but I'm not sure how make this do what I want.

I'd like the script to search all the 'a' tags within the "resourceTiles" div and remove the tiles where the link name in the 'p' tag does not match by adding the display: none style.

Is this the best way to approach this goal?

Comment: Be careful with using global variables inside functions, as you may screw things up elsewhere. Read about using `var` inside functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the function `resourceFilter`, you need to format it as a function in the html event handler `onkeyup`.  Other than that, it seems to work fine.  So your html should be:

```
<input type="text" id="resourceSearch" onkeyup="resourceFilter()" placeholder="Filter resources by name..">
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been banging my head against my desk all day trying to figure out what I was doing wrong and I totally overlooked my HTML.